# Print the name of selected item from dropdownlist to a label

Tags: asp.net

What can I do to make my selections appear on the label instantly?  I know the combobox but I couldn't figure out how dropdownlist works. I tried this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new List<string> { "111", "222", "333" };
        ddChoose.DataSource = items;
        ddChoose.DataBind();
    }



 protected void ddChoose_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddChoose.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "111";
        }
        if (ddChoose.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "222";
        }
    }
```

Comment: seems you are using asp.net try..updating with JS..let me know if you need help

Comment: I have not used javascript in my life and i am new to asp.net. I just want to run dropdownlist like combobox running in windows form app because i know it. @Always_a_learner

Comment: let me try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Default.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddChoose" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddChoose_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

## Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var items = new List<string> { "111", "222", "333" };
            ddChoose.DataSource = items;
            ddChoose.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddChoose_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl1.Text = ddChoose.Text;
    }
```

Comment: that didn't help @Allen

Comment: dropdownlist must set AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: I swear it is true

Comment: I think there was a problem saving, now I saved 2 times and it has improved. Sorry. and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically dropdown was bind again on each postback event . Change load event code in this way to prevent re-binding to dropdown:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
            var items = new List<string> { "111", "222", "333" };
            DropDownList1.DataSource = items;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Make sure AutoPostBack property of dropdown is set to True.

Comment: What are you seeing now?

Comment: my label's default text

Comment: is postback event triggered? Make sure AutoPostBack property of dropdown is set to True. there is nothing more with your code?

Comment: yes i made it true. Of course there are other things in my code but not about the dropdownlist.

Comment: You must have something which is restraining label to update as i test this small piece of code..working fine..

Comment: Libraries? using System.IO;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;